# ocaml hashtbl remove function

Tags: ocaml

How come the Hashtbl remove restores the previous binding.

```
Hashtbl.add t key1  
Hashtbl.remove t key1  
Hashtbl.remove t key1  => This should do anything but not restore the key1 !
```

Anyway, how come I can remove something making sure and if it was deleted before then proper flow shall be followed?

[val remove : ('a, 'b) t -> 'a -> unit
Hashtbl.remove tbl x removes the current binding of x in tbl, restoring the previous binding if it exists. It does nothing if x is not bound in tbl.](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Hashtbl.html)

Answer (score 6):

There are two legitimate mode of uses of `Hashtbl`: always using `Hashtbl.replace`, which ensures that each key only has one binding in the table, or using the table as a multi-mapping (each key pointing to a list of values) with `Hasthbl.add`, `Hashtbl.find` and `Hashtbl.find_all`.

Please make sure that you understand which mode of use you're interested in. There is no point in adding several bindings to the same key if you don't want to keep old bindings (this can result in performance issues, memory leaks and stack overflows); in that case you should use `Hashtbl.replace` instead of `Hashtbl.add`, and `Hashtbl.remove` will do exactly what you expect.

If you are using the hashtable as a multi-mapping, and want a function that remove all bindings for a key, you can implement it yourslef (code untested):

```
let rec remove_all tbl key =
  if Hashtbl.mem tbl key then begin
    Hashtbl.remove tbl key;
    remove_all tbl key
  end
```

Edit: I just understood that another way to read your (hard to understand) question is "how can I make sure that there is a key to remove in the table, instead of silently doing nothing when `remove` is called?". cago provides a code snippet for that, in essence you can use `Hashtbl.mem` to check that the binding exists when you assume it should exist.

Comment: for Hashtbl.replace, Hashtbl.remove does crash when deleting unfound key

Comment: @blackmath what do you mean by "crash"? I just tested that, as described by the documentation, removing a non-existing key does nothing (no error).

Answer (score 2):

If you use `Hashtbl.replace` instead of `Hashtbl.add` you'll replace the current binding of the key in `t`. So the function `Hashtbl.remove` will not restore anything.

You can also write your own remove function :

```
let remove tbl key =
   if Hashtbl.mem tbl key then Hashtbl.remove tbl key
   else raise Nothing_to_remove_in_the_hashtbl

Hashtbl.replace t key1 value;;
remove t key1;;
remove t key1;;  (* raise Nothing_to_remove_in_the_hashtbl *)
```